# Getting "#N/A" for my "=importXML" function

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

Trying to scrape data from Messari.io. I'm trying to get "num active addresses" into a google sheet. For "num active addresses" to appear, one must click on the right-hand side of the field to make it viewable. Once seen the element is

```
< div class="rt-td" role="gridcell" style="flex: 80 0 auto; width: 80px;">
```

so my google sheet code is

```
=importxml("messari.io", "//div[@class='rt-td'//text()")
```

but I know I'm not close...can somebody help on the second argument?

Answer (score 0):

bad news, this website can't be scraped anyhow coz it's fully dependant on JavaScript and Google Sheets is not able to work with JS at all:

[image: 0]

Comment: what about this site?

https://explore.veforge.com/accounts

and the value for "accounts" on the upper right-hand side of the page?

=importxml("https://explore.veforge.com/accounts", "//div[@class='card-title total']")

^^ that's what I have, but still get NA for the value

Comment: kinda same: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I90O.png you can check it yourself if you click on the lock and select site settings and there disable JS and reload page